# I'm not sure how to write test coverage for this code

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I'm a neophyte to Apex and coding and I need help with covering this simple code:

```
    public class SubmitCaseController {

    public Case c { get; set; }
    public SubmitCaseController() { 
        c = new Case();
        c.recordtypeid='012c0000000xxxx';
        c.ownerid='00Gc000000xxxx';}

    public PageReference submitCase() {

       try{
           INSERT c;
           return new PageReference('/apex/thanks');
       }
       catch(Exception e){
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
       }
   }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried calling the constructor and then the submitCase() on the instance?

Comment: besides the answer below - you will want to get rid of those hard-coded IDs in the controller code - you can get recordTypeId from `Schema.Describe`; and ownerId should be fetched via a query on some `User`

Comment: honestly, i spent two days looking at documentation and felt like i was reading swahili. i can write very simple code but that's about it. i never learnt testing in school, and that was 10 years ago. my focus wasn't programming so i never invested much energy into this. so tldr: i haven't tried anything. posting to SE was after i'd spent a lot of time not understanding the things i was reading to help myself. @DanielBallinger

Comment: @IsySarah Fair enough. Everyone has to start somewhere. It's great when the site can help people who are just starting out. However, that needs to be balanced with the Q&A format and avoiding people asking for free consulting work. If you really are genuinely stuck and can show some effort has been put in then you should get some answers.

Comment: also fair! i apologise, cos i understand what it looks like, but honestly, my "attempts" were non functioning, and i could barely make sense of where to begin. even the (non-SF) devs on my team couldn't help out so i turned online. appreciate the input @DanielBallinger

Comment: Hi, just noticed that you accepted Ian's answer. Unfortunately, his test class will only get you part way there - esp with respect to Salesforce's guidelines for test classes - you generally need to assert that your code has run as expected - as I demonstrate. Ian has put all the work that I demonstrate into a single comment - hardly something that you can use. If you used his example, you are probably doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Apex class with the following code:

```
@isTest 
private class SubmitCaseControllerTest {
    static SubmitCaseController controller = new SubmitCaseController();

    static testMethod void testForCoverage() {
        controller.submitCase();
    }

    //TODO: The current test only cover most of the the code, add more tests with valid assertion. Also, cover the catch block.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you prob have no idea where to go - there are good help docs for this stuff, but I'll try to walk through the idea of what you should do:

First: Define your Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class TestCaseController {
    static testmethod void testController() {
```

Now, setup your page and controller for the optimum case:

```
        //set the page
        PageReference pageRef = Page.SubmitCaseController;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        //make a new case controller here
       thecontroller controller = new thecontroller();
```

Then assert that you were successful:

```
        //get the location of the success page
        String nextPage = controller.submitCase().getUrl();
        System.assertEquals('/apex/thanks', nextPage);
```

Now, try to make your submit fail, so you can get into your try/catch block:

```
        //now, make the submit fail - I assume removing one of the ids, esp the owner will make it fail
        controller = new thecontroller();
        controller.c.ownerId = null;
        controller.c.recordTypeId = null;

        nextPage = controller.submitCase().getUrl();
        System.assertEquals('/apex/[original_page]', nextPage);

        //make sure we have a message (it'll be the error)
        System.assertNotEquals(null,ApexPages.GetMessages().get(0));
```

Note, I didn't run this code and in some cases you'll need to rename variables and objects. In general it should get you to near 100% coverage in most cases.

Good Luck!!

Here are some links that may help:

[Stackexchange question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50230/visualforce-page-reference-custom-controller-test-class) (Contains an insert)

[SFDC Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_custom.htm) (Upsert only)

Comment: yes, I have no clue what i'm doing. my knowledge of java hasn't been touched in 10 years and this little project is a one-off. i appreciate the help. i'm getting a compile error: invalid type: thecontroller for this line:  controller = new theController();

Comment: ah, and most of the docs i've found show testing code that updates existing records, but not testing a simple insert like this. can you point me towards the ones to which you're referring?

Comment: Your controller is called `TestCaseController` so make that line `controller = new TestCaseController();`

Comment: thank you for adding in those links, helped a ton. cheers!